# MatLab graph figure from file

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I don't know how to plot a figure of a graph from a file in MatLab.

I've tryed this:

```
A=readcell("graph4.txt");
G=graph(A(:,1),A(:,2));
plot(G)

-------------------------------

Sample of .txt

ache 4
é-te 2
unhe 4
ilhe 3
olhe 3
inox 0

...
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Any error messages? What is stored in `A` and `G`? Can you paste the data from graph.txt into the question? If it's a large file then only include some lines so that we can see the format.

Comment: Error using matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList
Node IDs must both be numeric vectors, both be node names (specified as string vectors, character vectors, or cell arrays of character vectors), or both be categoricals.

Error in graph (line 325)
                    matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList(...

Error in AED_Project02 (line 2)
G=graph(A(:,1),A(:,2));

Comment: ache 4
é-te 2
unhe 4
ilhe 3
olhe 3
inox 0

.....

Comment: this is like ache 4 (another line) é-te 2 ...

Comment: Please edit the question, with proper formatting. There's a toolbar at the top when you edit. It's hard to read the comments. Also, please show exactly how the file is. Not a description, but actual copy-paste.

Comment: there's the sample under the code

Comment: You seem to be confusing a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) (a structure with vertices and edges) and a [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart) (a diagram used to represent relationships between data, also called a graph). If you're trying to plot a figure, then MATLAB's `graph()` is not what you want to use. What sort of plot are you looking for? Do you have an example of your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a bar chart here since your data appear to be categorical counts.

You can use `bar(X,Y)` ([MathWorks link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html)), but you'll want to convert the `X` to categorical first.

Here is an example with your text file. I used `readtable()` because I like working with tables, but you can use `textscan()`, `fileread()`, or whatever you prefer. Also, I like to set the y-axis ticks to be integers for bar plots since a whole number is expected.

```
fid = "graph4.txt"
data = readtable(fid)
bar(categorical(data.Var1), data.Var2)
set(gca,'ytick',0:10) % set y ticks to integers
```

[image]